# Laravel Policy return false ID's are the same

Tags: laravel

I have created policy (RelationPolicy), and add method view:

```
public function view(User $user, Relation $relation)
    {
        return $user->id === $relation->user_id;

    }
```

And then I have tried to use it with controller helper:

```
$relation = Relation::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
$this->authorize('view', $relation);
```

But it always give me "FALSE".

When I add `dd($user->id)` and `dd($relation->user_id)` add in the policy I get those id's:

`dd($user->id)`: 1
`dd($relation->user_id)`: "1"

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
public function view(User $user, Relation $relation)
    {
        return $user->id == $relation->user_id;

    }
```

or

```
public function view(User $user, Relation $relation)
    {
        return $user->id === (int)$relation->user_id;

    }
```